# Variable contains a null value after selecting checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two projects that are running alongside, an ASP.NET Core MVC 5.0 web  project & and a ASP.NET Core Web API 5.0 project. When selecting any desired checkbox and typing a number into the textbox and hitting next when debugging I noticed that in my post action `SecIndex()` method the variable `phoneNumberInput` contains the fields `PhoneNumber` and `plans`. `PhoneNumber` will hold the value I entered in the textbox, but `plans` is `null`. I cannot seem to understand why `plans` is `null` when it should contain the ones I selected. *Is there something that is causing it to return `null` and not the values that I selected?*

[image]

[image]

[image]

MVC Project:

`Controller` where I am calling my API:

```cs
public IActionResult SecIndex()
{
    // call planapi
    var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result;
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Reached the Second Page View....");
    var x = new Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput { plans = result }; //So that you don't need to change the model in the view and the parameter type in the HttpPost Action.
    return View(x);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SecIndex(Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput phoneNumberInput)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "User successfully entered their phone number.");
            return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex", "Final");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "User missed to enter their phone number");
            throw new Exception("User did not enter a phone number in the textfield!");
        }     
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Empty textfield!");
        return View(phoneNumberInput);
    }
}
```

`RetrievePlans()` call in `SecIndex()`:

```cs
public async Task<List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>> RetrievePlans()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/plans/AvailablePlans");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>>(result);
    return json;
}
```

View in MVC:

```
@model Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput

<h2>Second page</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.plans.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
        <input hidden value="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
        <input hidden value="@Model.plans[i].PlanName" />

        <label for="Model.plans[i].PlanId"> @Model.plans[i].PlanName </label>
        <br />
    }

    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.PhoneNumber)
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />

    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.PhoneNumber) </p>
}
<script>
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                this.nextElementSibling.name = "plans[" + count + "].PlanId";
                this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.name = "plans[" + count + "].PlanName";
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**I attempted to place a breakpoint inside of `<script>` but the breakpoint will never be hit. Even if I select a value, could this be the reason why `plans` is `null?`**

Then in API project:

`ViewPhoneNumberInput` model class:

```cs
public class ViewPhoneNumberInput
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You did not enter your phone number! Please enter your phone number!")]
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Plans> plans { get; set; }
}
```

`Plans` model class:

```cs
public class Plans
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public string PlanName { get; set; }
}
```

`Controller` for API:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("AvailablePlans")]
public List<Plans> GetPlan()
{
    var _model = new ViewPhoneNumberInput();
    _model.plans = new List<Plans>();

    _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
    _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
    _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
    _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
    _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });

    var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_model.plans);
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);    

    return _model.plans;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below contains only parts related to View-Controller.

The `Selected` property is added to the `Plan`: this change makes the view content more simple. Actually, after making this simple change no need to use the JavaScript for processing the checkbox state.

The data model:

```cs
public class Plan
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    public string PlanName { get; set; }        
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class ViewPhoneNumberInput
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You did not enter your phone number! Please enter your phone number!")]
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public List<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult SecIndex(ViewPhoneNumberInput model)
{            
    if ( model == null || model.Plans == null)
    {
        var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result;       
        model = new Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput { Plans = result };
                 
        ModelState.Clear(); 
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Processing(ViewPhoneNumberInput data)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var plan in data.Plans)            
        {
            if (plan.Selected)
            {
                /* processing the selected plan */ 
            }                
        }
        return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex", "Final");            
    }
    else
    {
        return View("SecIndex", data);
    }
}
```

The `SecIndex.cshtml`:

```
@model Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput

@{ ViewBag.Title = " "; }

<h2>Store List</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Processing", "Home"))
{
    for (int i=0; i < Model.Plans.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.Plans[i].Selected)          
            <label>  @Model.Plans[i].PlanName</label><br />

            @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.Plans[i].PlanId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.Plans[i].PlanName)
        </div>
    }

    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => Model.PhoneNumber)
    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => Model.PhoneNumber) </p>

    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented your suggestion and when I hit the URL /Second/SecIndex I got a different view than I was expecting. Please check the original post. Do you get that as well?

Comment: when you said to call the RetrievePlans in that section I did `plans = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result`

Comment: @MarkCo: I make some fixes in the post.  Try to apply these fixes.

Comment: Thank you! Whenever I do `ModelState.Clear;` it tells me CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. Did you get that as well?

Comment: @MarkCo: Typo error: it should be `ModelState.Clear();` Sorry.

Comment: No worries, when I hit the next button, it says No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5443/Home/Processing. In regards to using the javascript, is there a reason why it is not hitting that <script> tag causing `plans` inside of `phoneNumberInput` to be null? The PhoneNumber stores its just the `plans` that is null.

Comment: @MarkCo: Pay attention, I changed name and declaration of `public IActionResult SecIndex(Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput phoneNumberInput)` to `public IActionResult Processing(ViewPhoneNumberInput data)`! You does not fix it. Therefore you received **_No webpage was found for the web address: localhost:5443/Home/Processing**_. I made this to avoid the duplicate error.
Perhaps it is necessary to change the controller name in `Html.BeginForm("Processing", "Home"))` from `Home` to your controller name.

Comment: Thank you! If I am wanting to pass both the planId & planName over to the next page (return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex", "Final") , inside of the `(if plan.Selected)` can I create a `static public var` that contains those values and just call it in the other view (finalindex) or is there a correct way in passing both values over to the next page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235718/discussion-between-jackdaw-and-markco).